How to add correctly an additional language for spell checking in Visual Studio?
I'm trying to get Visual Studio to check spelling in two languages, but it only works with English:
I found the following resources:

Visual Studio Blog => Visual Studio Spell Checker Preview Now
Available
Learn about the Spell Checker

Here’s an example from the documentation:

Here are some examples and use-case scenarios of the switches you can configure in an
EditorConfig file:
List the languages for Visual Studio to use. In this example, Visual Studio would only use the "en-us" and "fr-fr" dictionaries when
checking for spelling issues.
spelling_languages = _language_[,_language_]
(Example: = en-us,fr-fr)
Note
Make sure to install the language pack for any language you're using to prevent Visual Studio from incorrectly flagging words as
spelling errors.

I’ve installed the German language pack and placed a .editorconfig file in two locations:
Root directory (c:\.editorconfig)
Project directory (c:\Repo\Company\Solution\MyProject\.editorconfig)

With this content:
spelling_languages = en-us, de-de

However, Visual Studio still doesn’t suggest German words. Here's an image showing the issue:

Expected behavior (for two languages):

I've verified that the German language pack is installed:

Any ideas on what could be going wrong or how I can fix this?


Add .editorconfig File(.NET) item in project.

Open with HTML Editor.

Remove the space:  en-us, (space) de-de.
spelling_languages = en-us,de-de


save config file



I have tested your approach and it actually works.
However, if you add the .editorconfig via Add=>New Item=>.editorconfig File(.NET), many more settings are added that I did not want to define at this point.
Among other things, this editorconfig was defined as the authoritative one with “root = true”.
I therefore now have my .editorconfig like this:
# Include all files: [*.*] spelling_languages = en-us,de-de
It is also not necessary to include the file in the project.
My .editorconfig is now in the root folder under C:/
